# Webflow RequestContextHolder Returns Null RequestContext

Tags: spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I need to run an AJAX method from one of the pages in my webflow. According to the docs, this is what RequestContextHolder is for.

So, here is my method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="training/test", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public GridItem getGridItems() {

    RequestContext requestContext = RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext();
    Set<String> fsKeyset = requestContext.getFlowScope().asMap().keySet();
    for (String key: fsKeyset) {
        log.debug(key);
    }
    Form form = (Form) requestContext.getFlowScope().get("form");

    return form.getGridItem();

}
```

Unfortunately, the RequestContext is null. Is there something special I need to do to actually GET the RequestContext?

Jason

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your flow/view definition look like this

```
<view id="someId" view="someView" model="entity">

<transition on="ajaxSave" to="handleAjaxActionState"/>
<transition on="save" to="handleStandardSave"/>
</view>
```

then the bare min for your ajax url would look like:

```
url=${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=ajaxSave&ajaxSource=true
```

executing this (while you are still inside "someId" view state) will then get picked up in the "ajaxSave" transition.

*disclaimer: I did not test the above example.*